# How to use YOURLS along with domain alias configuration?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, alias, yourls

I have a domain, which is pointing to another domain to act as an alias for existing pages on the domain it's pointing to. Now, I would also like to use this domain alias to create separate short links, but I've been unable to do so.

My current htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?short\.link [NC] # alias domain
RewriteRule ^(admin|css|images|includes|js|pages|user)/ - [L] # folders that wont be redirected
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://long.link/article/$1 [R,L] # where alias is pointing to
```

YOURLS requires this htaccess entry:

```
# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS
```

Now the question is, how do I combine these two, so that when there's an existing YOURLS redirection, then YOURLS is prefered, but if not, then htaccess domain redirection is used? Perhaps this could be achieved somehow with the "fallback URI" ([code](http://pastebin.com/rWsKfQza)) - a YOURLS plugin used to redirect non-existing shortlinks, but I have no idea how.

Comment: ˇI still need help with this

Comment: ever solve this?